# Using a soundswitch to activate a relay

Tags: amplifier, relay, 555

I'd like as an end state of my project for sound to activate a relay and then either

- a) the relay to stay on for a limited amount of time (~15 seconds) or
- b) ideally - the relay to be triggered off with another sound

I understand that either of these can be achieved with a 555 timer chip, I am loathe to use option a) because I hear that they can be fairly inaccurate when it comes to lower time limits (e.g. 15 seconds)

Here is what I have currently

[image]

Microphone can be found here https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9964

The LED flickers pleasantly in time to music. This seems problematic for a bistable switch - because I can imagine that the sound activation (ideally a shout, or a knock) will have to many pauses and lilts for it to trigger the bistable switch only once - I think this is a phenomena called bounce.

ACTUAL QUESTIONS:

Is this circuit dangerous?
How could it be improved?
How do I fulfil option a) or b)?
Why if I put a capcitator (I've tried a range of capacitances and ceramic and electrolytic types) before the LED and after the resistor the LED will no longer turn on.

Comment: Why three transistors?

Comment: You need ["The Clapper"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clapper)!

Comment: Assuming your circuit works at all, those can't be PNP transistors. If they're NPN, then you just have a "triple Darlington" that's boosting the current available from the microphone. If you're putting a capacitor in series with the LED, that's blocking the DC current it needs to operate.

Comment: 3 transistors - I assume that each one amplifies the signal from the microphone enough to power the LED. One on its own didn't work

They're P2N2222A - which I thought were PNP, the internet has proved me wrong. Thanks!

@DaveTweed - I'd rather build the clapper myself!

Answer (score 1):

you can design the circuit using IC555 and CD4033(D-Flip Flop).By using an SPDT switch you can select option a or b.

Comment: may i know why you are using a capacitor in series with LED

Comment: That was a sort of general question. I understand why it doesn't work now. The capcitator blocks DC current.

I ended up building it with a 555 timer only. I used the same idea as this. But with a transistor to let current through rather than a pushed switch. With the base of the transistor attached to the microphne

Comment: can you post your schematic